# Error serving static website using erlang yaws

Tags: web, erlang, yaws

I have a web application build using dotnet as the backend and reactjs as the frontend. I build the front end files and want to serve them using yaws. I have the following configuration in `/etc/yaws/conf.d/localhost.conf`:

```
<server localhost>
    port = 8080
    listen = 0.0.0.0
    docroot = /var/www/apps/foobar/build
    dir_listings = true 
</server>
```

I am using the default `yaws.conf` file.

The directory `/var/www/apps/foobar/build` has the build files:

```
assets
favicon.svg
index.html
manifest.json
robots.txt
static
```

I am able to get to the homepage but I am getting 404 page not found for subsequent pages. i.e., login page or signup pages. The same works fine with nginx.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without additional information. Where are your login and signup pages in your directory structure? If we assume your home page URL is `http://example.com:8080/index.html`, what URLs are you using for the login and signup pages? You should consider running `yaws` interactively by avoiding the `--daemon` option and using `-i` instead, and also using `--trace` so that all traffic is logged to the standard output. (Use the Erlang "Ctrl-g q" key sequence to exit interactive mode.)

Comment: This is a React SPA build so I only have the index.html page. The routes /login.html /signup.html are dynamically rendered. http://example.com:8080/index.html , http://example.com:8080/login.html, http://example.com:8080/singup.html etc. this is how the pages are rendered when deployed on nginx. Sorry for being dumb but this is my first web application.

Comment: I know no details about React but if it's sending long polling or websocket requests, then you'll need to write an application module, or `appmod`, to be able to handle those. Search for `appmod` in the Yaws documentation. Note that this will require some Erlang programming knowledge.